# Proving $x^5+\frac{1}{|\cos x|+1}=1$ has at least one solution in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the equation $$x^5+\frac{1}{|\cos x|+1}=1$$ has at least one solution in $(0,\infty)$

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: What Jack said, yes we do know.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Telling us these things will help people write an answer at your level of knoweldge and they may be able to point out where you are going wrong

Comment: value 1/2 at 0, value > 1/2 at 1, intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the graphs $y=x^5$, $y=\frac1{|\cos x|+1}$, and $y=1$ and looking at them as a start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution to exist in (0, $\infty$), $x$ must be less than 1, for we know that the $x^5$ is greater than 1 for $x>1$ and further, that the value of the expression $\frac{1}{|cos(x)| + 1}$ is always positive for $x$ $\epsilon$ $(0,1)$.

Now, we can easily deduce that $x^5$ is strictly increasing, continuous and differentiable, in $(0,1)$.

For the expression, $\frac{1}{|cos(x)| + 1}$, we know from properties of $cos$ that it is positive, strictly decreasing, continuous and differentiable in $(0, \pi/2)$ and therefore in $(0,1)$ too. $cos(x)$ being positive in $(0,1)$, we can drop the absolute value operator around it. Now $1+cos(x)$ is also decreasing in $(0,1)$. But once we invert $1+cos(x)$ (which is $\frac{1}{1+|cos(x)|}$), we get a strictly increasing function which ranges from $1/(1+cos(0))$ i.e. $1/2$, to, $1/(1+cos(1))$, i.e. 0.649.. in the interval $(0,1)$.

Now we have 2 expressions, one ($x^5$) which ranges from $0$ to $1$ and the other $\frac{1}{1+|cos(x)|}$ which ranges from $0.5$ to $0.649..$, both in the interval of (0,1).

We can conclusively say that sum of the both the expressions must range from $(0.5, 1.649)$. Also, we already know that both expressions are continuous and differentiable in $(0,1)$, so there must be a value of x $\epsilon$ $(0,1)$ such the sum of both expressions is 1, which can be one solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f (x)=x^5+\frac {1}{|\cos (x)|+1}-1$$

$f $ is continuous at $[0,\pi/2] $,

$$f (0)=-1/2 <0$$
and
$$f (\pi/2)>0$$
thus by IVT, the equation $f (x)=0$ has at least a solution at $(0,\pi/2) $.

Comment: How do we know $f$ is continuous in the region $[0, \pi/2]$?

Comment: @lioness99a because $|\cos (x)|+1\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks, might be worth adding that sentence to your answer, just in case

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful for my final exam revision